# MongoDB + Intel XDK

Tags: javascript, html5, mongodb, intel-xdk

Preciso utilizar o MongoDB dentro do Intel XDK, para logar, cadastrar, guardar coordenadas, depois exibir em um mapa, etc... Alguém tem alguma sugestão de ferramenta? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Este tutorial da própria Intel deve te ajudar (em inglês): https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/accessing-a-rest-based-database-backend-from-an-android-app

Comment: Use angular para fazer a interação ... mas não recomendo o XDK use o vscode ou outro editor de texto